# Save list number within a list only if it contains elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have list of lists such as :

```
my_list_of_list=[['A','B','C','E'],['A','B','C','E','F'],['D','G','A'],['X','Z'],['D','M'],['B','G'],['X','Z']]
```

as you can see, the `list 1` and `2` share the most elements (4). So, I keep a list within `my_list_of_list`  only if the 4 shared elements (**A**,**B**,**C** or **E**) are present within  that list.

Here I then save within the `list_shared_number[]`, only the lists 1,2,3 and 6 since the other does not contain  (**A**,**B**,**C** or **E**).

Expected output:

```
print(list_shared_number)
[0,1,2,5]
```

Comment: `A, B, C or D` or `A, B, C or E`?

Comment: Do you mean "E" instead of "D"? Also, do you mean at least one of the elements (A or B or C or E)? My last question is, do you wanna start from the position (1 being the subfirst list) or the index (0 being the first sublist)

Comment: Please attach what you tried.

Comment: A,B,C or E sorry, and I want a 0 index you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably sub optimal because I need to iterate 3 times over lists but it's the expect result:

```
from itertools import combinations
from functools import reduce

common_elements = [set(i).intersection(j) 
                       for i, j in combinations(my_list_of_list, r=2)]

common_element = reduce(lambda i, j: i if len(i) >= len(j) else j, common_elements)

list_shared_number = [idx for idx, l in enumerate(my_list_of_list)
                          if common_element.intersection(l)]
print(list_shared_number)

# Output
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

Alternative with 2 iterations:

```
common_element = {}
for i, j in combinations(my_list_of_list, r=2):
    c = set(i).intersection(j)
    common_element = c if len(c) > len(common_element) else common_element
list_shared_number = [idx for idx, l in enumerate(my_list_of_list)
                          if common_element.intersection(l)]
print(list_shared_number)

# Output
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `itertools.combinations` and set operations.

In the first line, you find the intersection that is the longest among pairs of lists. In the second line, you iterate over `my_list_of_list` to identify the lists that contain elements from the set you found in the first line.

```
from itertools import combinations
comparison = max(map(lambda x: (len(set(x[0]).intersection(x[1])), set(x[0]).intersection(x[1])), combinations(my_list_of_list, 2)))[1]
out = [i for i, lst in enumerate(my_list_of_list) if comparison - set(lst) != comparison]
```

Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can find shared elements by using list comprehension. Checking if index 0 and index 1:

```
share = [x for x in my_list_of_list[0] if x in my_list_of_list[1]]
print(share)
```

Assume `j` is each item so `[j for j in x if j in share]` can find shared inner elements. if the length of this array is more than 0 so it should include in the output.

So final code is like this:

```
share = [x for x in my_list_of_list[0] if x in my_list_of_list[1]]
my_list = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list_of_list) if len([j for j in x if j in share]) > 0]
print(my_list)
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you shuffle the list. You need to use all possible combinations to find the longest common set.

Comment: why? problem is `share` variable? I get from the question that shared elements should extract from my_list_of_list[0] and my_list_of_list[1]; is it true?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it's just an example. The OP wants to find the longest common set first in the whole list.

Comment: It should be clarified in the question. I try to include your comment in my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh boy, so mine is a bit messy, however I did not use any imports AND I included the initial "finding" of the two lists which have the most in common with one another. This can easily be optimised but it does do exactly what you wanted.

```
my_list_of_list=[['A','B','C','E'],['A','B','C','E','F'],['D','G','A'],['X','Z'],['D','M'],['B','G'],['X','Z']]
my_list_of_list = list(map(set,my_list_of_list))
mostIntersects = [0, (None,)]

for i, IndSet in enumerate(my_list_of_list):
    for j in range(i+1,len(my_list_of_list)):
        intersects = len(IndSet.intersection(my_list_of_list[j]))
        if intersects > mostIntersects[0]: mostIntersects = [intersects, (i,j)]
FinalIntersection = set(my_list_of_list[mostIntersects[1][0]]).intersection(my_list_of_list[mostIntersects[1][1]])

skipIndexes = set(mostIntersects[1])
for i,sub_list in enumerate(my_list_of_list): 
    [skipIndexes.add(i) for char in sub_list 
        if i not in skipIndexes and char in FinalIntersection]

print(*map(list,(mostIntersects, FinalIntersection, skipIndexes)), sep = '\n')
```

The print provides this :

```
[4, (0, 1)]
['E', 'C', 'B', 'A']
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

This works by first converting the lists to sets using the map function (it has to be turned back into a list so i can use len and iterate properly) I then intersect each list with the others in the list of lists and count how many elements are in each. Each time i find one with a larger number, i set mostIntersections equal to the len and the set indexes. Once i go through them all, i get the lists at the two indexes (0 and 1 in this case) and intersect them to give a list of elements [A,B,C,E] (var:finalIntersection). From there, i just iterate over all lists which are not already being used and just check if any of the elements are found in finalIntersection. If one is, the index of the list is appended to skipIndexes. This results in the final list of indexes {indices? idk} that you were after. Technically the result is a set, but to convert it back you can just use list({0,1,2,5}) which will give you the value you were after.